# Initialiser with protocol generics not working

Tags: swift

I have a protocol with generics:

```
protocol DataService {
  associatedtype T

  var getData: ((T) -> Void)? { get set }
}
```

Which I'm attempting to use as the parameter in an initialiser:

```
class MyProvider {
  var service: DataService

  init(service: DataService) {
    self.service = service
  }
}
```

However, I keep getting:

```
Protocol 'DataService' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

I've tried the code below but it did not work:

```
init<T: String>(service: DataService) {
  self.service = service
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a generic class instead:

```
class MyProvider<T> where T: DataService {
    var service: T

    init(service: T) {
        self.service = service
    }
}
```